# JavaScript Menu Builder

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm building this menu builder with JS. So far I have a simple version 1 implementation that does what I want but it needs improving. Couple of things that I'd like to improve:

- Prevent unwanted input
- Control input when there is margin for error, ie for the *target* field I'd like to have either a drop down or a checkbox.
- Maintain state between page load (menu should remain on page after load)
- Any code optimization

Here is the full code and [a link to codepen](https://codepen.io/ryan_pixelers/details/eBXXyP/):

```
// track the button clicks globally
var btnClicks = 0;

// create a function the append the form to the DOM on page load.
window.onload = createForm;

function createForm() {

  // initialize out form container
  var f = formContainer();

  // declare the variables we will use in one place
  var itemName, id, className, target, href, btn, text, h2;

  // create an array that will hold the values we wish to pass to our links
  // in the menu
  var listItem = [itemName, id, className, target, href];

  // Create the labels so each input can have a unique label
  var labels = ['Name', 'ID', 'Class', 'Target', 'Link'];

  // Helper text
  h2 = document.createElement('h2');
  text = 'Fill in the fields below to create a new menu item';
  h2.innerText = text;
  f.appendChild(h2);

  // loop through the list items
  listItem.forEach(function(element, index){
    // for each element, call the createDOMNode function and pass in required data
    element = createDOMNode(labels[index], 'input', 'text', 'input_' + index);
    // append each element to the form container
    f.appendChild(element);
  });

  // create the button and give it an onclick handler
  btn = document.createElement('button');
  btn.innerText = 'Create Menu Item';
  f.appendChild(btn);
  btn.onclick = getUserInput;
}

// get what the user inputted into the fields
function getUserInput() {
  // initialize some variables and an array
  var itemName, id, className, target, href;
  item = [];

  // access the values from the input fields
  values = [
    itemName = document.getElementById('input_0').value,
    id = document.getElementById('input_1').value,
    className = document.getElementById('input_2').value,
    target = document.getElementById('input_3').value,
    href = document.getElementById('input_4').value,
  ];

  // loop through each value
  values.forEach(function(element, index){
    // and push it into the item[] array
    if(element !== '') {
      item.push(element);
    }
  });

  // make sure required items are filled out
  if(values[0] === '' && values[4] === '') {
    alert('Name and Link are both required');
  } else if(values[0] === '') {
    alert('Name is required');
  } else if(values[4] === '') {
    alert('Link is required');
  }

  // if the array is not empty, then create the menu
  if(item.length !== 0) {
    createMenu(item);
  }

  // increase the button counter
  btnClicks += 1;

}
var nav = document.createElement('nav');
var ul = document.createElement('ul');
// function to create a new menu
function createMenu(item) {
  // create elements needed for menu

  var li = document.createElement('li');
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  var f = document.getElementById('formContainer');

  // trying to create the nav only on the first click
  if(btnClicks < 1) {
    nav.setAttribute('class', 'nav');
    document.body.insertBefore(nav, f);
    nav.appendChild(ul);
  }

  var arrayLength = item.length;
  // loop through items and set their attributes
  for(var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    li.appendChild(a);
    a.innerText = item[0];
    a.setAttribute('id', item[1]);
    a.setAttribute('class', item[2]);
    a.setAttribute('target', item[3]);
    a.setAttribute('href', item[4]);

  }
  // and append them to the ul
  ul.appendChild(li);
}

function formContainer() {

  // create the element and set where it is displayed in the DOM
  var formContainer = document.createElement('div');
  formContainer.setAttribute('id', 'formContainer');
  var scriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  // document.body.insertBefore(formContainer, scriptTag);
  document.body.appendChild(formContainer);

  // style the element
  formContainer.style.width = '360px';
  formContainer.style.margin = '0 auto';
  formContainer.style.border = '1px solid #ddd';
  formContainer.style.padding = '15px';

  return formContainer;

}


function createDOMNode(label, element, type, id) {

  var l = document.createElement('label');
  l.innerText = label;

  // create the node and set it's type attribute
  var node = document.createElement(element);
  node.setAttribute('type', type);
  node.setAttribute('id', id);

  // style the node
  node.style.padding = '8px 4px';
  node.style.width = '100%';
  node.style.marginBottom = '10px';
  node.style.boxSizing = 'border-box';

  l.appendChild(node);

  return l;
}
```

Comment: Please note that questions asking for [advice about code not yet written](http://meta.CodeReview.StackExchange.com/a/3651) are off-topic. Please [follow the tour](http://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/tour) and read ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask), ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Sorry. I thought it was complete. It's a complete version 1...

Comment: I'm referring to things like "I'd like to have" etc. Right now it sounds like you want us to provide things like a solution to "Maintain state between page load" etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## createForm()

I don't think you need the `listItem` array or its named elements at all; you're not using it for anything. To build the form controls, you can loop through the `labels` array instead of the `listItem` array.

```
// loop through the list items
labels.forEach(function(element, index){
    // for each element, call the createDOMNode function and pass in required data
    // then append the result to the form container
    f.appendChild(createDOMNode(labels[index], 'input', 'text', 'input_' + index));
});
```

## getUserInput()

You're missing the `var` keyword before defining the variable `item`.

There's no reason to define variables for `itemName`, `id`, `className`, `target`, and `href`, since you never reference those values by name. You can just populate your `values` array directly.

```
values = [
    document.getElementById('input_0').value,
    document.getElementById('input_1').value,
    document.getElementById('input_2').value,
    document.getElementById('input_3').value,
    document.getElementById('input_4').value,
];
```

## consider objects with named properties as alternatives to arrays

In general, I think your code is over-using arrays to store values that are not inherently suited to that data structure.

A good example of this is the use of the `values` array and `item` array in `getUserInput()`.

You're populating `values` with values from the text boxes, then looping through those values to check whether they're blank, and if not, you're then pushing those values into the `item` array to represent your actual item.

Consider instead capturing those values directly into an object, as below.

```
// access the values from the input fields
var item = {
    name: document.getElementById('input_0').value,
    id: document.getElementById('input_1').value,
    class: document.getElementById('input_2').value,
    target: document.getElementById('input_3').value,
    link: document.getElementById('input_4').value,
};
// make sure required items are filled out
if(item.name === '' && item.link === '') {
    alert('Name and Link are both required');
} else if(item.name === '') {
    alert('Name is required');
} else if(item.link === '') {
    alert('Link is required');
} else {  // if the array is not empty, then create the menu
    createMenu(item);
}
```

This saves you all the processing that would take place within the loop.

You would also need to update your `createMenu()` function to accommodate the new format for the `item` parameter.

```
// function to create a new menu
function createMenu(item) {
    // create elements needed for menu
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    var a = li.appendChild(document.createElement('a'));
    var f = document.getElementById('formContainer');

    // trying to create the nav only on the first click
    if(btnClicks < 1) {
        nav.setAttribute('class', 'nav');
        document.body.insertBefore(nav, f);
        nav.appendChild(ul);
    }

    a.innerText = item.name;
    a.setAttribute('id', item.id);
    a.setAttribute('class', item.class);
    a.setAttribute('target', item.target);
    a.setAttribute('href', item.link);
    ul.appendChild(li);
}
```

Notice also that you had an unnecessary loop in the `createMenu()` function which did the same thing 5 times in a row (set the inner text and attributes of the `a` element).

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Funny that I had actually already considered a lot of your points but wasn't sure how to do it the way you suggested. I'll give it try